# Most Active Contributors Monthly Report - September 2018

Tags: discussion, most-active-contributors, announcement

## Welcome to the 12th edition of the monthly Ask Different Most Active Contributors Report.

Please don't hesitate to share your valuable feedback in the comments.

[image: TITLE: REPORT TITLE]

### Report for September 2018

This report includes the following sections:

1. Overall Most Active Contributors Award
2. Monthly Reputation Leader Board
3. Most Active Editors Award
4. Most Active Voters Award
5. Most Active Close Vote Reviewers
6. Most Active First Post Reviewers
7. Most Active Late Answer Reviewers
8. Most Active Low-Quality Post Reviewers
9. Most Active Reopen Post Reviewers
10. Most Suggested Edits Reviewed Award
11. Highest Voted Questions Award
12. Highest Voted Answers Award
13. Most Viewed Questions Award
14. Ranked 1st Summary List
15. Moderators Activity Summary

---

[image: TITLE: OVERALL MOST ACIVE CONTRIBUTORS AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                  SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   Nimesh Neema              410
2   Monomeeth                 320
3   bmike                     280
4   Allan                     210
5   grg                       140
```

**Note:** This is an overall ranking based on all activities. Maximum possible score = 850.

---

[image: TITLE: MONTHLY REPUTATION LEADER BOARD]

[image]
A total of 1,605 users earned reputation during the month. You can view the full list [here](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/118/month/apple/2018-09-01).

---

[image: TITLE: MOST ACTIVE EDITORS AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                  EDITS
---------------------------------------
1   Nimesh Neema              171
2   bmike                     136
3   abc                       119
4   Monomeeth                  55
5   IconDaemon                 41
```

A big thank you to all 21 users who edited questions or answers this month!

---

[image: TITLE: MOST ACTIVE VOTERS AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                  VOTES
---------------------------------------
1   PeterJ                  1,332
2   Monomeeth                 434
3   bmike                     349
4   Nimesh Neema              329
5   LangLangC                 225
```

A big thank you to all 64 users who voted on questions or answers this month!<sup>1</sup>

<sup>1. Note: Only users who have voted over 10 times in the period are counted in this metric.</sup>

---

[image: ![TITLE: MOST ACTIVE CLOSE VOTE REVIEWERS]

```
#   WINNER                  SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   Nimesh Neema               62
2   Mark                       53
3   Allan                      48
4   bmike                      46
5   fsb                        41
```

A big thank you to all 21 users who reviewed Close Votes this month!

---

[image: TITLE: MOST ACTIVE FIRST POST REVIEWERS]

```
#   WINNER                  SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   Nimesh Neema              372
2   Monomeeth                 315
3   fsb                       101
4   jaume                      70
5   grg                        62
```

A big thank you to all 27 users who reviewed First Posts this month!

---

[image: ![TITLE: MOST ACTIVE LATE ANSWERS REVIEWERS]

```
#   WINNER                  SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   Monomeeth                 149
2   Allan                      52
3   Glorfindel                 50
4   grg                        43
5   Nimesh Neema               38
```

A big thank you to all 23 users who reviewed Late Answers this month!

---

[image: ![TITLE: MOST ACTIVE LOW-QUALITY POST REVIEWERS]

```
#   WINNER                  SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   Nimesh Neema               38
2   Allan                      26
3   fsb                        25
4   jaume                      20
5   Mark                       18
```

A big thank you to all 21 users who reviewed Low-Quality Posts this month!

---

[image: ![TITLE: MOST ACTIVE REOPEN POST REVIEWERS]

```
#   WINNER                  SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   Allan                      10
2   bmike, nohillside           7
3   Nimesh Neema, Mark          6
4   Tetsujin, jaume             4 
5   grg, Glorfindel, Mark,
    fsb, IconDaemon, Monomeeth  2
```

A big thank you to all 16 users who reviewed Reopen Votes this month!

---

[image: ![TITLE: MOST ACTIVE SUGGESTED EDIT REVIEWERS]

```
#   WINNER                  SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   Nimesh Neema              110
2   Monomeeth                  81
3   bmike                      70
4   Allan                      40
5   grg                        28
```

A big thank you to all 44 users who reviewed Suggested Edits this month!

---

[image: TITLE: HIGHEST VOTED QUESTION AWARD]

1. [My Mac repeatedly beeps three times on startup. What does this mean?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/335649/my-mac-repeatedly-beeps-three-times-on-startup-what-does-this-mean)

   - Posted by: user301113
   - Votes: **29**
2. [Do iPhone X cases fit on the iPhone XS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/336889/do-iphone-x-cases-fit-on-the-iphone-xs)

   - Posted by: npkllr
   - Votes: **11**
3. [How to get dark menu bar and dock in Mojave light mode?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/337478/how-to-get-dark-menu-bar-and-dock-in-mojave-light-mode)

   - Posted by: Jay Wong
   - Votes: **10**

---

[image: TITLE: HIGHEST VOTED ANSWER AWARD]

1. [My Mac repeatedly beeps three times on startup. What does this mean?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/335649/my-mac-repeatedly-beeps-three-times-on-startup-what-does-this-mean/335651#335651)

   - Posted by: Monomeeth
   - Votes: **45**
2. Tied result:

   [Is there a script I can use to download the Mojave installer without being signed in to the App Store?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/337450/is-there-a-script-i-can-use-to-download-the-mojave-installer-without-being-signe/337453#337453)

   - Posted by: bmike
   - Votes: **14**

   [Change iPhone pin remotely](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/335845/change-iphone-pin-remotely/335846#335846)

   - Posted by: fsb
   - Votes: **14**
3. [Windows has MS Word. What does Mac have as a word processor?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/335916/windows-has-ms-word-what-does-mac-have-as-a-word-processor/335917#335917)

   - Posted by: Monomeeth
   - Votes: **13**

---

[image: TITLE: MOST VIEWED QUESTION AWARD]

1. [Do iPhone X cases fit on the iPhone XS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/336889/do-iphone-x-cases-fit-on-the-iphone-xs)

   - Posted by: npkllr
   - Views: **13,678**
2. [My Mac repeatedly beeps three times on startup. What does this mean?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/335649/my-mac-repeatedly-beeps-three-times-on-startup-what-does-this-mean)

   - Posted by: user301113
   - Views: **5,442**
3. [Silverlight Plug-In in Safari 12](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/336838/silverlight-plug-in-in-safari-12)

   - Posted by: Passe
   - Views: **5,156**

---

[image: TITLE: RANKED 1st SUMMARY LIST]

**1.    Overall Most Active Contributors Award**

- [Nimesh Neema](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/279727/nimesh-neema)

**2.    Monthly Reputation Leader Board**

- [Nimesh Neema](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/279727/nimesh-neema)

**3.    Most Active Editors Award**

- [Nimesh Neema](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/279727/nimesh-neema)

**4.    Most Active Voters Award**

- [PeterJ](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/83841/peterj)

**5.    Most Active Close Vote Reviewers Award**

- [Nimesh Neema](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/279727/nimesh-neema)

**6.    Most Active First Post Reviewers Award**

- [Nimesh Neema](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/279727/nimesh-neema)

**7.    Most Active Late Answer Reviewers Award**

- [Monomeeth](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/users/168832/monomeeth)

**8.    Most Active Low-Quality Post Reviewers Award**

- [Nimesh Neema](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/279727/nimesh-neema)

**9.    Most Active Reopen Post Reviewers Award**

- [Allan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/119271/allan)

**10.   Most Active Suggested Edit Reviewers Award**

- [Nimesh Neema](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/279727/nimesh-neema)

**11.   Highest Voted Questions Award**

- [user301113](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/301113/user301113)

**12.   Highest Voted Answers Award**

- [Monomeeth](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/users/168832/monomeeth)

**13.   Most Viewed Questions Award**

- [npkllr](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/301662/npkllr)

---

[image: TITLE: MODERATORS ACTIVITY SUMMARY]

In September our [Moderators](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) actioned 459 flags with an average handling time of 25 minutes. In summary, we also:

- deleted 420 comments
- deleted 246 posts
- closed 120 posts
- edited 254 posts
- created 98 posts
- created 467 comments

---

Please join me in thanking all contributors for volunteering their time to make this site so great. We appreciate the contributions made by all users, not just those listed in this report!

Keep up the great work! :)